# How to Reverse singly linked list properly in C?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

well im starting with C and i've been asked to do a linked list that has random integers in its nodes data, they must be in ascendant order and later i have to reverse their order with a function. The problem im having is that in my reverse output, im only getting the first number and its not even reversed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int N;

typedef struct node{
int num;
struct node *next;
}nodes;

int first_node(nodes *head){
if(head == NULL){
    printf("Error");
}
  else{
    head -> num= rand();
    head->next=NULL;
    }
}

int second_node(nodes *head){
nodes *uno=malloc(sizeof(nodes));
if(uno == NULL){
    printf("Error");

}

else{
    uno->num = rand();
    uno->next = NULL;
            if( uno->num>head->num){
               head->next=uno;

            }
            else{
                head= uno->next;
            }

}

}

int insert_node(nodes *head){
    nodes *dos=malloc(sizeof(nodes));
    if(dos == NULL){
        printf("Error");

    }

    else{
        dos->num = rand();
        dos->next = NULL;


        nodes *current = head;
        while(current!= NULL){
                if(current->num<dos->num && current->next==NULL){
                    current->next = dos;
                    return;

                }

                else if (current->num<dos->num && current->next->num>dos->num){
                dos->next=current->next;
                current->next=dos;
                return;

                }
                else if(head->num>dos->num){
                dos->next=head;
                head=dos;

        }
        current=current->next;

    }

}}

void printnodes(nodes *head){
    nodes *current = head;
    while (current != NULL){
        printf("%d\n",current->num);
        current = current ->next;
    }


}



void reverse(nodes *head)
{
 nodes *a=head->next;
 if(a!=NULL)
 {
   nodes *b=a->next;
   a->next=head;
   head->next=NULL;
   head=a;
   if(b!=NULL)
   {
     while(b!=NULL)
     {
      a=b;
      b=b->next;
      a->next=head;
      head=a;
     }
     a->next=head;
     head=a;
   }

   }
 }

int main(){
printf("Insert the number of nodes u want to create:");
scanf("%d", &N );
nodes *head =malloc(sizeof(nodes));
int i =3;

if(N==1){
    first_node(head);
}
else if (N ==2){
    first_node(head);
    second_node(head);

}
else if (N>2){

    first_node(head);
    second_node(head);
           while(i<=N){
            insert_node(head);
            i++;
           }
}


printnodes(head);
printf("\n\n Reversed \n\n");

reverse(head);
printnodes(head);


return 0;


}
```

The output im getting creating 5 nodes is :
In order: 
41
3445
3890
8709
16777

Reversed :
**41**

how can i fix this?, thanks and sorry for the bad english

Comment: What did you find out by debugging the reversal?

Comment: This code does not compile. Can you post the necessary code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two very obvious problems in your code:

The first is that you assign to a local variable, expecting that assignment to be reflected once the function returns. I'm talking about your assignment to `head` in most functions. The problem here is that when you pass an argument to a function. it's passed *by value*, meaning it's copied and what you have in the function you call is just a copy or the original value. And as you should know, changing a copy will not change the original.

The second problem that I see at a quick glance is in the `second_node` function, where you first do

```
uno->next = NULL;
```

and potentially followed by

```
head= uno->next;
```

This will assign `NULL` to `head`.

The first problem is easy to solve, by *emulating* something called *pass by reference*. I say emulating, as C only have pass by value. You can emulate pass by reference in C using pointer, which means that to pass a pointer "by reference" in C, you have to pass a pointer to the pointer, like

```
int second_node(nodes **head){
    ...
}
```

You then call it using the address-of operator:

```
second_node(&head);
```

Then in `second_node` you use the dereference operator `*` to access the "original" `head` pointer, like

```
*head = uno->next;
```

---

Writing the above I noticed a *third* problem, and that is that you declare some functions as returning an `int`, but you don't actually return anything from the functions. Thankfully it seems that you don't use the returned value anywhere, but it's still is *undefined behavior* to not return a value in a function that should return a value. If you should not return a value from a function it must be declared as returning `void`:

```
void second_node(nodes **head){...}
```